# discord.py -> как сделать сообщение которое отправиться на все сервера, а также что-бы небыло спама, лишь одно сообщение на каждый сервер

Tags: discord.py

Например:
(префикс)(команда) (сообщение)

Данное сообщение должно отправиться на все сервера в первый доступный канал!

Answer (score 0):

Есть два варианта, и оба костыльные.


**1 вариант**.

Отправлять сообщение в первый созданный на сервере канал. **НО**, если канал приватный, то сообщение увидят только те пользователи, которые имеют доступ к этому каналу.

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, message=None):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        await guild.text_channels[0].send(message)
```

**2 вариант**.
Отправлять сообщение в новостной канал сервера. **НО**, если новостного канала на сервере нет, тогда бот ничего на данный сервер не отправит.

```
@bot.command()
async def send(ctx, message=None):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            if channel.type == discord.ChannelType.news:
                await guild.text_channels[0].send(message)
```

К сожалению в Дискорде нету функции выбрать на сервере основной канал для общения, так что бот не сможет отправить сообщение в этот канал.

Вы можете попробовать объединить эти два кода, возможно у Вас что-то получится.

Удачи!